# Computing an integral involving standard normal pdf and cdf - with peculiar limits.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I have had a look at some of the other questions on this topic but cannot quite work out the solution to this integral (or prove that there isn't a solution).  Is there a way to work out:

\begin{equation}
\int^{A}_{-\infty} \int^{B-Cx}_{-\infty} \phi(y) \ \phi(x)\ dy \ dx
\end{equation}

Where $A \in \mathbf{R}$, $B>0,C >0$, and $\phi(.)$ is the standard normal pdf.

Some of the previous responses to similar questions have used polar coordinates.  If this is a possible route, I have been unable to work out a simple way to convert the limits.  Further, integration by parts has not yielded much success either.

Perhaps another way of framing this problem is that I am trying to find the probability of a bivariate normal on a peculiar domain.

I very much appreciate the help!  Thanks.

Comment: If plucking only low-hanging unripened fruit will help, the case $B = C$ allows the use of symmetry to get some not completely satisfactory bounds. This is the kind of problem looked at by digital communications folks where it is the probability of correctly receiving a signal that has two nearest neighbors, with the three signals being $(X,Y)$, conditionally independent normal random variables with means that are non-collinear points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, and $(x_3,y_3)$, so that the decision boundaries are the medians of the triangle formed by these three points.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Dilip!  Having spent some more time digging around, I suspect that the only way forward here is through some form of numerical approximation (or at least series expansion).  If you don't mind me asking, do you know where I could get some papers by the digital communications folk that you mentioned?

Comment: There are _many_ books on digital communications. [Here](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/wcsl/Publications/ch2thru6_dec2012.pdf) is one that is a work in progress.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to get an exact closed-form result as far as I know, 
but you can get a union bound
(upper bound) on the *complementary* probability. The *complement* of the event $\{X \leq A, Y \leq B-CX\}$ is, by DeMorgan's law, the *union* of the events $\{X > A\}$ and $\{Y > B-cX\}$, and so
$$\begin{align*}
P\{X \leq A, Y \leq B-CX\} &= 1 - P\bigr(\{X > A\} \cup \{Y > B-CX\}\bigr)\\
&\geq 1 - \bigr[P\{X > A\}  + P\{Y > B-CX\} \bigr]
\end{align*}$$
Now, $P\{X > A\} = Q(A)$ where $Q(\cdot)$ is the complementary standard
normal CDF while $$P\{Y > B-CX\} = P\{Y + CX > B\} = Q\left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{1+C^2}}\right)$$
since $Y+CX$ is a zero-mean normal random variable with variance $1+C^2$.
Since $Q(a)$ is a rapidly decreasing function for $a > 0$, this lower bound
can be pretty tight when $A\gg 0$ and $B \gg C$.